# Is it possible to Launch a VBScript from a HTA Program?

Tags: vbscript, hta

I need some help, as the title implies, is there anyway that I can launch a VBS file from a HTA application? If not, would there be any application that can be launched by a HTA file that I can then use to launch another file/program?

**EDIT**

This problem has been resolved.

Comment: Research WShell.Run and then (perhaps) ask for answers to *specific* questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using javascript as your scripting language in hta, then this could be a solution:

```
function openApp(sApp)  { 
    var oShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell"); 
    oShell.Run(sApp); 
}
```

And then in your markup:

```
<a href="#" onclick="openApp('notepad.exe'); window.focus();">Click here</a>
```